# Using cookies with Brython

Tags: python, cookies, brython

I’m currently trying to handle cookies with Brython but I’m having some trouble. I’ve found the `local_storage` module in the docs. When I set a cookie using this module, the server can’t find them (using `request.COOKIES` in a Django `views.py` function).
What’s weird, is that the value is stored because when I reload the page, the script prints it in the console.

The code in the HTML page:

```
<script type="text/python">
    from browser.local_storage import storage
    import random

    if 'test' in storage:
        print(storage['test'])
    storage['test'] = str(random.randint(0, 100))
    print(storage['test'])
</script>
```

Each time I reload the page, the value I get is the one that was stored but the cookie does not exist on the server side (`request.COOKIES` does not contain a key `'test'`).

Maybe there’s something I’m missing?

**Edit:**

So, after looking at this page (link from Brython docs) https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webstorage.html, I discovered that local storage is not the same thing as cookies but they rather are similar sytems existing side by side.

So my question now is how can I use cookies with Brython instead of local storage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, it turns out it was pretty simple. The code is pretty much the same as in JavaScript.

Here is some sample code for creating a cookie named `foo` with the value `bar`:

```
from browser import document

document.cookie = 'foo=bar; Path=/'
```

And that’s it!